# Failed to open port /dev/ttyUSB0

Tags: ros, roslaunch, turtlebot, turtlebot-bringup, icreate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
Failed to open port /dev/ttyUSB0.  Please make sure the Create cable is plugged into the computer.
```

this is the message I get when I try to run

`roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch`

The cable is plugged in to the computer, but it can't seem to find it. Any advice? Thanks!

---

```
hyness@turtlebot:~$ roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch
... logging to /home/hyness/.ros/log/e48df4ec-e303-11e1-b4b3-94dbc99cb3ba/roslaunch-turtlebot-28662.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://192.168.1.101:53917/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /app_manager/interface_master
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/digital_io/path
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/digital_io/startswith
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/digital_io/timeout
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/digital_io/type
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/mode/path
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/mode/startswith
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/mode/timeout
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/mode/type
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/nodes/contains
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/nodes/path
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/nodes/timeout
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/nodes/type
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/power/path
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/power/startswith
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/power/timeout
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/power/type
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/sensors/path
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/sensors/startswith
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/sensors/timeout
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/sensors/type
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/base_path
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/pub_rate
 * /robot/name
 * /robot/type
 * /robot_description
 * /robot_pose_ekf/freq
 * /robot_pose_ekf/imu_used
 * /robot_pose_ekf/odom_used
 * /robot_pose_ekf/output_frame
 * /robot_pose_ekf/publish_tf
 * /robot_pose_ekf/sensor_timeout
 * /robot_pose_ekf/vo_used
 * /robot_state_publisher/publish_frequency
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /turtlebot_laptop_battery/acpi_path
 * /turtlebot_node/bonus
 * /turtlebot_node/update_rate
 * /use_sim_time

NODES
  /
    app_manager (app_manager/app_manager)
    appmaster (app_manager/appmaster)
    diagnostic_aggregator (diagnostic_aggregator/aggregator_node)
    robot_pose_ekf (robot_pose_ekf/robot_pose_ekf)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/state_publisher)
    turtlebot_laptop_battery (turtlebot_node/laptop_battery.py)
    turtlebot_node (turtlebot_node/turtlebot_node.py)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.101:11311

core service [/rosout] found
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[appmaster-1]: started with pid [28714]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[app_manager-2]: started with pid [28715]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[turtlebot_node-3]: started with pid [28717]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[turtlebot_laptop_battery-4]: started with pid [28721]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[robot_state_publisher-5]: started with pid [28731]
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/turtlebot/turtlebot_node/nodes/turtlebot_node.py:54: UserWarning: roslib.rosenv is deprecated, please use rospkg or rosgraph.rosenv
  import roslib.rosenv
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[diagnostic_aggregator-6]: started with pid [28735]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[robot_pose_ekf-7]: started with pid [28767]
turtlebot_apps.installed
loading installation data for [turtlebot_apps.installed]
[INFO] [WallTime: 1344878483.388894] serial port: /dev/ttyUSB0
[INFO] [WallTime: 1344878483.390361] update_rate: 30.0
[INFO] [WallTime: 1344878483.391525] drive mode: twist
[INFO] [WallTime: 1344878483.392730] has gyro: True
[INFO] [WallTime: 1344878483.524643] self.gyro_measurement_range 150.000000
[INFO] [WallTime: 1344878483.525284] self.gyro_scale_correction 1.350000
[INFO] [WallTime: 1344878483.606566] Starting app manager for turtlebot
[INFO] [WallTime: 1344878483.649391] Waiting for foreign master [http://localhost:11312] to come up...
[INFO] [WallTime: 1344878483.661190] Foreign master is available
[INFO] [WallTime: 1344878483.705600] Registering (/turtlebot/app_list,http://192.168.1.101:36448/) on master http://localhost:11312
[INFO] [WallTime: 1344878483.722560] Registering (/turtlebot/application/app_status,http://192.168.1.101:36448/) on master http://localhost:11312
turtlebot_apps.installed
[INFO] [WallTime: 1344878483.738635] Registering service (/turtlebot/list_apps,rosrpc://192.168.1.101:48816) on master http://localhost:11312
[INFO] [WallTime: 1344878483.753652] Registering service (/turtlebot/start_app,rosrpc://192.168.1.101:48816) on master http://localhost:11312
[INFO] [WallTime: 1344878483.768299] Registering service (/turtlebot/stop_app,rosrpc://192.168.1.101:48816) on master http://localhost:11312
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1344878486.591044] Failed to open port /dev/ttyUSB0.  Please make sure the Create cable is plugged into the computer. 

Failed to open port /dev/ttyUSB0.  Please make sure the Create cable is plugged into the computer.
```

________________________________________________________________________________--

EDIT:

```
hyness@turtlebot:~$ dmesg | grep ttyUSB
[   19.480585] usb 4-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[264451.156468] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[264453.577268] usb 4-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[268339.617586] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[268349.513718] usb 8-2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[339739.939792] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[339742.652429] usb 8-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[339762.109603] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[339770.306100] usb 4-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[339794.598883] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[339813.176481] usb 8-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[339844.747131] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[339893.004286] usb 8-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[340327.577148] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[340329.547441] usb 8-2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0

hyness@turtlebot:~$ ls /dev/ttyUSB*
/dev/ttyUSB0
```

---

**There were too many results, and some of them were cut off; here is what I can see**

```
[   19.518791] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   19.518796] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[   21.106684] [drm] PCIE GART of 512M enabled (table at 0x0000000000040000).
[   21.106902] radeon 0000:00:01.0: WB enabled
[   21.123507] [drm] ring test succeeded in 1 usecs
[   21.123815] [drm] radeon: ib pool ready.
[   21.123991] [drm] ib test succeeded in 0 usecs
[   21.124725] [drm] Radeon Display Connectors
[   21.124729] [drm] Connector 0:
[   21.124732] [drm]   LVDS
[   21.124735] [drm]   HPD1
[   21.124739] [drm]   DDC: 0x6430 0x6430 0x6434 0x6434 0x6438 0x6438 0x643c 0x643c
[   21.124742] [drm]   Encoders:
[   21.124745] [drm]     LCD1: INTERNAL_UNIPHY
[   21.124748] [drm] Connector 1:
[   21.124750] [drm]   HDMI-A
[   21.124753] [drm]   HPD2
[   21.124756] [drm]   DDC: 0x6440 0x6440 0x6444 0x6444 0x6448 0x6448 0x644c 0x644c
[   21.124759] [drm]   Encoders:
[   21.124762] [drm]     DFP1: INTERNAL_UNIPHY
[   21.124764] [drm] Connector 2:
[   21.124766] [drm]   VGA
[   21.124770] [drm]   DDC: 0x64d8 0x64d8 0x64dc 0x64dc 0x64e0 0x64e0 0x64e4 0x64e4
[   21.124773] [drm]   Encoders:
[   21.124776] [drm]     CRT1: INTERNAL_KLDSCP_DAC1
[   21.124822] [drm] Internal thermal controller without fan control
[   21.124924] [drm] radeon: power management initialized
[   21.417147] type=1400 audit(1344614080.668:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=752 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   21.417400] type=1400 audit(1344614080.668:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=848 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   21.418053] type=1400 audit(1344614080.668:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=752 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   21.418328] type=1400 audit(1344614080.668:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=848 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   21.418579] type=1400 audit(1344614080.668:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=752 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   21.418858] type=1400 audit(1344614080.668:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=848 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   21.420116] type=1400 audit(1344614080.672:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=786 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   21.421332] type=1400 audit(1344614080.672:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=786 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   21.422023] type=1400 audit(1344614080.672:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=786 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   21.595083] [drm] fb mappable at 0xC0142000
[   21.595089] [drm] vram apper at 0xC0000000
[   21.595092] [drm] size 4325376
[   21.595095] [drm] fb depth is 24
[   21.595097] [drm]    pitch is 5632
[   21.595517] fbcon: radeondrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[   21.595717] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 170x48
[   21.595769] fb0: radeondrmfb frame buffer device
[   21.595772] drm: registered panic notifier
[   21.595787] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.12.0 20080528 for 0000:00:01.0 on minor 0
[   21.595946] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:01.1: PCI INT B -> GSI 19 (level, low) -> IRQ 19
[   21.596113] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:01.1: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[   21.596155] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:01.1: setting latency timer to 64
[   22.166950] HDMI status: Codec=0 Pin=3 Presence_Detect=0 ELD_Valid=0
[   22.167484] input: HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/sound/card0/input8
[   22.168917] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:14.2: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[   22.667532] input: HDA ATI SB Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card1/input9
[   22.667729] input: HDA ATI SB Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card1/input10
[   24.208539] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   24.751053] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   24.751066] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   24.751070] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   25.056329] type=1400 audit(1344614084.308:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=955 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   25.374570] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   25.374578] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   25.664430] init: failsafe main process (914) killed by TERM signal
[   29.180643] audit_printk_skb: 3 callbacks suppressed
[   29.180650] type=1400 audit(1344614088.432:13): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=1061 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   29.181594] type=1400 audit(1344614088.432:14): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=1061 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   29.182122] type=1400 audit(1344614088.432:15): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=1061 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   29.301942] type=1400 audit(1344614088.552:16): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session-wrapper" pid=1060 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   29.338987] r8169 0000:06:00.0: eth0: link down
[   29.339870] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   29.340680] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   29.379476] type=1400 audit(1344614088.628:17): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" pid=1064 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   29.380700] type=1400 audit(1344614088.632:18): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/telepathy-*" pid=1064 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   29.392618] type=1400 audit(1344614088.644:19): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=1066 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   29.393710] type=1400 audit(1344614088.644:20): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1066 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   30.198607] type=1400 audit(1344614089.448:21): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/bin/evince" pid=1062 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   30.209567] type=1400 audit(1344614089.460:22): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/bin/evince//launchpad_integration" pid=1062 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   38.044681] input: Sony Playstation SixAxis/DS3 as /devices/virtual/input/input11
[   39.950793] init: plymouth-stop pre-start process (1495) terminated with status 1
[   66.674852] audit_printk_skb: 21 callbacks suppressed
[   66.674859] type=1400 audit(1344614125.925:30): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" name="/usr/share/gvfs/remote-volume-monitors/" pid=2028 comm="mission-control" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[   93.632144] eth1: no IPv6 routers present
[ 1089.780340] init: turtlebot main process (10252) terminated with status 1
[ 1089.780479] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1089.914035] init: turtlebot main process (10275) terminated with status 1
[ 1089.914118] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1090.062557] init: turtlebot main process (10293) terminated with status 1
[ 1090.062692] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1090.216002] init: turtlebot main process (10311) terminated with status 1
[ 1090.216218] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1090.365281] init: turtlebot main process (10330) terminated with status 1
[ 1090.365376] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1090.505878] init: turtlebot main process (10349) terminated with status 1
[ 1090.506012] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1090.654396] init: turtlebot main process (10367) terminated with status 1
[ 1090.654522] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1090.806787] init: turtlebot main process (10386) terminated with status 1
[ 1090.806871] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1090.950699] init: turtlebot main process (10404) terminated with status 1
[ 1090.950777] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1091.095898] init: turtlebot main process (10422) terminated with status 1
[ 1091.096100] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1091.250507] init: turtlebot main process (10440) terminated with status 1
[ 1091.250590] init: turtlebot respawning too fast, stopped
[ 1093.583821] init: turtlebot main process (10477) terminated with status 1
[ 1093.583907] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1093.710527] init: turtlebot main process (10499) terminated with status 1
[ 1093.710610] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1093.860354] init: turtlebot main process (10518) terminated with status 1
[ 1093.860450] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1094.010746] init: turtlebot main process (10540) terminated with status 1
[ 1094.010828] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1094.156003] init: turtlebot main process (10558) terminated with status 1
[ 1094.156283] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1094.304175] init: turtlebot main process (10576) terminated with status 1
[ 1094.304255] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1094.447348] init: turtlebot main process (10595) terminated with status 1
[ 1094.447429] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1094.611998] init: turtlebot main process (10613) terminated with status 1
[ 1094.612211] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1094.761463] init: turtlebot main process (10635) terminated with status 1
[ 1094.761547] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1094.905125] init: turtlebot main process (10654) terminated with status 1
[ 1094.905208] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1095.047440] init: turtlebot main process (10672) terminated with status 1
[ 1095.047573] init: turtlebot respawning too fast, stopped
[ 1095.897909] init: turtlebot main process (10702) terminated with status 1
[ 1095.898205] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1096.051617] init: turtlebot main process (10724) terminated with status 1
[ 1096.051789] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1096.204070] init: turtlebot main process (10742) terminated with status 1
[ 1096.204210] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1096.354565] init: turtlebot main process (10761) terminated with status 1
[ 1096.354699] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1096.505661] init: turtlebot main process (10779) terminated with status 1
[ 1096.505760] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1096.649149] init: turtlebot main process (10797) terminated with status 1
[ 1096.649283] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1096.800127] init: turtlebot main process (10815) terminated with status 1
[ 1096.800214] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1096.951878] init: turtlebot main process (10834) terminated with status 1
[ 1096.951962] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1097.096739] init: turtlebot main process (10852) terminated with status 1
[ 1097.096821] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1097.250754] init: turtlebot main process (10870) terminated with status 1
[ 1097.250837] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1097.396069] init: turtlebot main process (10889) terminated with status 1
[ 1097.396209] init: turtlebot respawning too fast, stopped
[ 1097.639494] init: turtlebot main process (10911) terminated with status 1
[ 1097.639593] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1097.781413] init: turtlebot main process (10929) terminated with status 1
[ 1097.781491] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1097.903070] init: turtlebot main process (10949) terminated with status 1
[ 1097.903148] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1098.050512] init: turtlebot main process (10967) terminated with status 1
[ 1098.050606] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1098.192434] init: turtlebot main process (10993) terminated with status 1
[ 1098.192562] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1098.344092] init: turtlebot main process (11011) terminated with status 1
[ 1098.344231] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1098.485245] init: turtlebot main process (11030) terminated with status 1
[ 1098.485379] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1098.632992] init: turtlebot main process (11048) terminated with status 1
[ 1098.633087] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1098.778058] init: turtlebot main process (11066) terminated with status 1
[ 1098.778146] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1098.938351] init: turtlebot main process (11089) terminated with status 1
[ 1098.938486] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1099.091582] init: turtlebot main process (11107) terminated with status 1
[ 1099.091711] init: turtlebot respawning too fast, stopped
[ 1100.169944] init: turtlebot main process (11133) terminated with status 1
[ 1100.170034] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1100.317039] init: turtlebot main process (11158) terminated with status 1
[ 1100.317117] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1100.458252] init: turtlebot main process (11178) terminated with status 1
[ 1100.458334] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1100.595709] init: turtlebot main process (11196) terminated with status 1
[ 1100.595793] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1100.748492] init: turtlebot main process (11214) terminated with status 1
[ 1100.748626] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1100.898055] init: turtlebot main process (11233) terminated with status 1
[ 1100.898138] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1101.043998] init: turtlebot main process (11251) terminated with status 1
[ 1101.044206] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1101.189231] init: turtlebot main process (11269) terminated with status 1
[ 1101.189367] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1101.350655] init: turtlebot main process (11287) terminated with status 1
[ 1101.350798] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1101.500721] init: turtlebot main process (11310) terminated with status 1
[ 1101.500856] init: turtlebot main process ended, respawning
[ 1101.644145] init: turtlebot main process (11328) terminated with status 1
[ 1101.644283] init: turtlebot respawning too fast, stopped
[264451.156150] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[264451.156468] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[264451.156499] ftdi_sio 4-1:1.0: device disconnected
[264453.388266] usb 4-1: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ohci_hcd
[264453.573264] ftdi_sio 4-1:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[264453.573381] usb 4-1: Detected FT232RL
[264453.573391] usb 4-1: Number of endpoints 2
[264453.573398] usb 4-1: Endpoint 1 MaxPacketSize 64
[264453.573405] usb 4-1: Endpoint 2 MaxPacketSize 64
[264453.573412] usb 4-1: Setting MaxPacketSize 64
[264453.577268] usb 4-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[268339.616955] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 4
[268339.617586] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[268339.617649] ftdi_sio 4-1:1.0: device disconnected
[268340.545423] usb 8-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[268340.545436] usb 8-2.2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[268343.623578] keyboard: can't emulate rawmode for keycode 240
[268343.623608] keyboard: can't emulate rawmode for keycode 240
[268343.623621] asus_wmi: Unknown key 57 pressed
[268349.484292] usb 8-2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[268349.512790] ftdi_sio 8-2:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[268349.512909] usb 8-2: Detected FT232RL
[268349.512919] usb 8-2: Number of endpoints 2
[268349.512927] usb 8-2: Endpoint 1 MaxPacketSize 64
[268349.512934] usb 8-2: Endpoint 2 MaxPacketSize 64
[268349.512941] usb 8-2: Setting MaxPacketSize 64
[268349.513718] usb 8-2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[272939.358154] keyboard: can't emulate rawmode for keycode 240
[272939.358184] keyboard: can't emulate rawmode for keycode 240
[272939.358198] asus_wmi: Unknown key 58 pressed
[339739.939265] usb 8-2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[339739.939792] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[339739.939855] ftdi_sio 8-2:1.0: device disconnected
[339742.624352] usb 8-1: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[339742.651197] ftdi_sio 8-1:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[339742.651314] usb 8-1: Detected FT232RL
[339742.651324] usb 8-1: Number of endpoints 2
[339742.651332] usb 8-1: Endpoint 1 MaxPacketSize 64
[339742.651340] usb 8-1: Endpoint 2 MaxPacketSize 64
[339742.651346] usb 8-1: Setting MaxPacketSize 64
[339742.652429] usb 8-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[339762.109074] usb 8-1: USB disconnect, device number 5
[339762.109603] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[339762.109662] ftdi_sio 8-1:1.0: device disconnected
[339770.116342] usb 4-1: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ohci_hcd
[339770.302041] ftdi_sio 4-1:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[339770.302267] usb 4-1: Detected FT232RL
[339770.302277] usb 4-1: Number of endpoints 2
[339770.302285] usb 4-1: Endpoint 1 MaxPacketSize 64
[339770.302292] usb 4-1: Endpoint 2 MaxPacketSize 64
[339770.302299] usb 4-1: Setting MaxPacketSize 64
[339770.306100] usb 4-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[339794.598255] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 5
[339794.598883] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[339794.598943] ftdi_sio 4-1:1.0: device disconnected
[339813.148352] usb 8-1: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[339813.175554] ftdi_sio 8-1:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[339813.175669] usb 8-1: Detected FT232RL
[339813.175679] usb 8-1: Number of endpoints 2
[339813.175687] usb 8-1: Endpoint 1 MaxPacketSize 64
[339813.175694] usb 8-1: Endpoint 2 MaxPacketSize 64
[339813.175701] usb 8-1: Setting MaxPacketSize 64
[339813.176481] usb 8-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[339844.746489] usb 8-1: USB disconnect, device number 6
[339844.747131] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[339844.747191] ftdi_sio 8-1:1.0: device disconnected
[339892.976115] usb 8-1: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[339893.003507] ftdi_sio 8-1:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[339893.003622] usb 8-1: Detected FT232RL
[339893.003632] usb 8-1: Number of endpoints 2
[339893.003640] usb 8-1: Endpoint 1 MaxPacketSize 64
[339893.003648] usb 8-1: Endpoint 2 MaxPacketSize 64
[339893.003654] usb 8-1: Setting MaxPacketSize 64
[339893.004286] usb 8-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[339904.726020] keyboard: can't emulate rawmode for keycode 240
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41275/failed-to-open-port-/dev/ttyusb0/) by [buma676](https://answers.ros.org/users/2990/buma676/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2012-08-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe *udev* has assigned another device name to your *Create cable* (/dev/ttyUSB1, /dev/ttyUSB2...)?

Here are some commands that might help you identify the correct device name:

```
ls /dev/ttyUSB*
dmesg | grep ttyUSB
```

Once you find the correct device name you should update your turtelbot configuration.

If neither of the above commands produces results, then there might be something wrong with your cable.

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2012-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PerkinsJames](https://answers.ros.org/users/2621/perkinsjames/) on 2012-08-14**:
Do a tail -f /var/log/messages and watch the messages as you plug in the USB cable.  This should tell you the device its naming it